# Model type reference not working in mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

It is working with `ViewData` and `ViewBag` but try to strongly type model binding that unable to build Model type reference

What I am missing anyone and  doing anything wrong.

### View:

```
@model  Working_with_Views.Models.Product;
@{
  var product  = Model;
}
<h3>Name: @product.Title</h3>
<h2>Price: @product.Price</h2>
<h5>Produce Date: @product.ProduceDate</h5>
```

view page compile time error

[image]

### Model:

```
namespace Working_with_Views.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ImgePath { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProduceDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime  LeftDateExpire { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Product product = new Product()
        {
            Title = "Pepsi",
            Price = 30.00m,
            ProduceDate = DateTime.Now,
            LeftDateExpire = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
        };

        return View(product);
    }
```

Comment: You need to remove the `;` after the model declaration (and add the code and the error message in your question, not an image of it)

Comment: How i think it is need ; end of the statement or not

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Comment: "You need to remove the ; after the model declaration" but why ? why  not working if use the ; after the model declaration.cloud you explain me :)

Comment: Because you need to. That's the way the code works

Comment: you are using razor so you have to follow the syntax of razor for code to work

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `model` to the view or using it via `ViewBag` and `ViewData` is two totally different ways of doing the same thing. The ways of implementing each is very different.

In your case you are incorrectly passing the model to the view - as a matter of fact you are not even passing it through. You are only specifying where the model can be found. You need to specify the whole `namespace` including the model name, in your case `Product`:

```
@model Working_with_Views.Models.Product
```

Now that you have passed the model to the view now you can use like you want.

Using the below is not convenient because how will the view know that your model is `Product` if you do not specify it? What happens if there are other models like `Customer`, `Address`, `Country`, etc? How does your view know it has to use `Product`?

```
@model  Working_with_Views.Models;
```

This is why you need to specify to the view the model that you are wanting to use.

You do not even need this part because you can use the model directly:

```
@{
     var product  = Model;
}
```

Removing the above mentioned code you can use the model that was passed in by the controller like this:

```
<h3>Name: @Model.Title</h3>
<h2>Price: @Model.Price</h2>
<h5>Produce Date: @Model.ProduceDate</h5>
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit more for you when using models in the view.

Comment: ops i  specified , unfortunately did not adding .now you see update my view